# Getting a Javascript object with JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm trying to get a javascript object, which I call 'items', from a MYSQL DB with the help of JSON. later I will use this javascript object to plot a chart. 
Right now I just want to print the variable 'items' in the 'body' section. (as seen the in the code).

I found a few suggested answers online: retrieveResults() and retrieveResults2(), but none of them worked, I'd appreciate any help.

right now I don't get any output at all from the 'document.write(items)', and I have no idea what is the reason for that.

the getdata.php file:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678','test');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"test");
$sql="SELECT * FROM example5 WHERE time = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $result_array[] = array($row['time'], $row['data']);
}
echo json_encode($result_array);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

the index.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        var items =[];

        function run(){
            $.getJSON('getdata.php', function(data) {


                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                });

                $('<ul/>', {
                    'class': 'my-new-list',
                    html: items.join('')
                }).appendTo('body');
            });
        }

        function retrieveResults2(str){
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: data,
                success: run
            });
        }

        function retrieveResults(str){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: {
                    q: str,
                }, 
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);

                    $.each(json, function(index, value) {
                    items.push(value); // Not sure if it is correct, you might need to do some changes, but this is for the global idea 
                    }
                }
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('An error occurred:'+errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        window.onload = retrieveResults2(1);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="users">
        <option value="">Select Time:</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="4">5</option>
        <option value="4">6</option>
        <option value="4">7</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(items);


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have an XHTML 1.0 Doctype with HTML 3.2 markup?

Comment: Don't concatenate user input into SQL queries, you are [vulnerable to SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Why are you using `run` as a success handler in your Ajax call but defining `run` to make a nearly identical Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

At the time you call `document.write()`, `items` is an empty array (because the HTTP response to your Ajax based HTTP request has not yet been received and processed).

You need to modify your document in your Ajax callback (and you need to do so using DOM and not `document.write` since `document.write` will destroy the existing document).

---

Also, you never make an ajax request where you pass a value for `q`, so your SQL query is probably going to throw an error and make the script die instead of giving you a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to index.html, you need to wrap your code to execute when the DOM is ready. A way to do that is wrapping inside $(document).ready(function() { //your code here });

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var items =[];

        $.getJSON('getdata.php', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
            });

            $('<ul/>', { class: 'my-new-list', html: items.join('')}).appendTo('body');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <select name="users">
        <option value="">Select Time:</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="4">5</option>
        <option value="4">6</option>
        <option value="4">7</option>
        </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```